# ssh: connect to host host port | No firewall

Tags: debian, ssh, iptables, timeout

I have a Debian server and I'm trying to access it by ssh from another server and I'm getting timeout error. I have **no iptables rules on any of them**, and actually I can ssh to target host from any other server and devices I have, The problem is just with this one server (which I can ssh to other servers from it without problem) and it's not just for port 22, when I do traceroute, I get Port Unreachable for port 22 and 80, but the host is reachable.
The only thing different about this one server is, it's not in the same region as others, Could it be some restriction applied by my Data center or ISP? It seems unlikely since I can ssh the second server from first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I used `tcpdump` to see how tow servers are communicating, I found out my target server does not receive any packet from my source server, I reported the problem to my Data Center and the problem was in one of the routers in their network.

Comment: I'd be good if you can edit the title so that future readers may recognize it as helpful for troubleshooting their similar problems.